# How to use curl for show list of file in directory?

Tags: linux, security, curl

I want to enter the following site:

```
https://www.example.com/files/download
```

I can't log in because of authentication. But I know the address of a specific file.

```
https://www.example.com/files/download/1.mp4
```

When I enter the above address, to my surprise, I am allowed to access the file. Probably a programming bug.

Now my question is, how can you access the general list of these files through tools like curl?

I was able to download the files through curl, but my goal is not to download the files, but I want to have the list of files.

```
curl -k -o file[1-6].mp4 https://example.com/file/download/[1-6].mp4
```

Comment: This is not programming or development, but it depends on the protocol(s) supported by the server and your build of curl (which can vary). Excluding protocols that don't have files or directories at all, `ftp[s]://user:pw@host/path` should always work (if those protocols work at all, which is rare on the modern public net), `sftp://sim/path_end_with_slash/`, `smb[s]:` I don't know, `http[s]:` varies depending on the server software and configuration and may not work at all.